# TypeScript React - iterate over props object

Tags: typescript, react-typescript, solid-js

When using TypeScript how do you loop through an object within a React (or SolidJS) components HTML? is there a correct syntax or does it require a work around?

```
export default function MyComponent(props: any) {
       
    return (
        <>
            {Object.values(props.someObject).map(value => {
                <div>{value.name}</div>       {/* Error: Object is of type 'unknown'. */}
            })}
        </>

    )
}
```

I'm following this SolidJS tutorial for context: https://youtu.be/WSvmEG7HPyE
Specifically id like to use the `<For>` loop component built into SolidJS which I believe is just a shorthand syntax of map.

```
<For each={props.someObject}>
{value =>
    <div>{value.name}</div>       {/* Error: Object is of type 'unknown'. */}
}
</For>
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple function like this would be useful for getting the props entries with correct types:

```
const propsEntries = <T extends Record<string, unknown>>(props: T) =>
  Object.entries(props) as [keyof T, T[keyof T]][];
```

Then it could be used to map over props using the `<For>` component:

```
<For each={propsEntries(props)}>
   {([name, value]) => <li>{name}: {value}</li>}
</For>
```

[demo in playground](https://playground.solidjs.com/?hash=-1861867707&version=1.4.1)

Answer (score 0):

In React + typescript you would need to do it in the following way.

```
type MyComponentProps = {
 someObject: object
}

export default function MyComponent(props: MyComponentProps) {
       
    return (
        <>
            {Object.values(props.someObject).map(value => {
                <div>{value}</div> 
            })}
        </>

    )
}
```